# Setting a seed for alglib decision forest implementation

Tags: random-forest, alglib

I am using alglib to train a random forest. I would like to actually train a number of forests using the same input data and the same set of input variables. To do this I need to control the seed of the random number generator but I can not find a way to access it. Does anyone knows whether such functionality is provided?